# Error in container(id = outputId, class = "shiny-text-output") : could not find function "container"

Tags: shiny

When I put the below in. I keep getting a error when i try to run the app.

## Define server logic required to draw a histogram

```
    server <- function(input, output) {
     output$txtOutput<- renderText({
      paste(input$txtInput)
      })
```

}> runApp('app3/HW1app.R')
Error in container(id = outputId, class = "shiny-text-output") :
could not find function "container"

Answer (score 0):

I know I am very late, but this happened to me when I gave to arguments to the `textOutput` (like this:  `textOutput("txt","Number doubled")`).

Instead you should only provide one argument:  `textOutput("txt")`. There is no label or such thing in `textOutput`, only the `outputId`.

Next time you ask a question you should provide a minimal working example. It is very hard for me now to know if your error had the same cause or not. In your specific case I guess the code you provided had no errors and the cause of the error were parts of the code that you did not share with us...